# Range Date Search on DataTables (CodeIgniter)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I need help.
I want to show the data's within the range of the date i choose.
Here's my code so far

Here's the code where I display the datatables

**View**

```
<div class="box-body">
          <div class="table-responsive">

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="form-group start-date">
                    <label>From</label>
                    <div class="input-group date">
                      <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                      </div>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="start_date" name="start_date">
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.input group -->
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="form-group end-date">
                    <label>To</label>
                    <div class="input-group date">
                      <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                      </div>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="end_date" name="end_date">
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.input group -->
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <div class="form-group met-cheq">
                      <label>Go </label>
                      <div class="input-group date">
                        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-md" name = "search" id="search">Search!</button> 
                      </div>
                      <!-- /.input group -->
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


            <table id="table-sales" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>DR</th>
                  <th>Date</th>
                  <th>Customer</th>
                  <th>Price</th>
                  <th>Paid Amnt</th>
                  <th>Balance</th>
                  <th>Receipt</th>
                  <th>Remarks</th>
                  <th>Items</th>
                  <th style="width:55px;">Action</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($sales_inv as $inv) {
                    $balance = $inv->inv_price-$inv->payment;
                    $status = "";
                    $payment = $inv->payment;

                    if ($inv->inv_type==1) {
                      $status = "Department Store";
                    }elseif($inv->inv_type==2){
                      $status = "Local";
                    }elseif($inv->inv_type==3){
                      $status = "Provincial";
                    }elseif($inv->inv_type==4){
                      $status = "UNITOP";
                    }elseif($inv->inv_type==5){
                      $status = "GAISANO";
                    }
                ?>
                  <tr class="row-<?php echo $inv->id; ?>">
                    <td><a href="#" class="btn-inv-show" data-value="<?php echo $inv->inv_cno; ?>@<?php echo $inv->id; ?>"><?php echo $inv->inv_cno; ?></a></td>
                    <td><?php echo date("M d, Y", strtotime($inv->timestamp)); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $inv->cust_name; ?></td>
                    <td class="price-<?php echo $inv->inv_cno; ?>">Php <?php echo number_format($inv->inv_price,2); ?></td>
                    <td class="payment-<?php echo $inv->inv_cno; ?>">Php <?php echo number_format($payment,2); ?></td>
                    <td class="bal-<?php echo $inv->inv_cno; ?>">Php <?php echo number_format($balance,2); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $status; ?></td>
                    <td>
                      <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-rem" data-value="<?php echo $inv->id; ?>">View Remarks
                      </button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-item" data-value="<?php echo $inv->inv_cno; ?>">View Item
                      </button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-print" data-value="<?php echo $inv->inv_cno; ?>"><i class="fa fa-print"></i></button>
                      <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs btn-add-pay" data-value="<?php echo $inv->inv_cno; ?>@<?php echo $inv->custid; ?>@<?php echo $inv->id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i></button>
                      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-edit-pay" data-value="<?php echo $inv->inv_cno; ?>@<?php echo $inv->custid; ?>@<?php echo $inv->id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                <?php } ?>
              </tbody>
              <tfooter>
                <tr>
                  <th>DR</th>
                  <th>Date</th>
                  <th>Customer</th>
                  <th>Price</th>
                  <th>Paid Amnt</th>
                  <th>Balance</th>
                  <th>Receipt</th>
                  <th>Remarks</th>
                  <th style="width:55px;">Action</th>
                </tr>
              </tfooter>
            </table>
          </div>
          <!-- /.table-responsive -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.box -->
    </section>
    <!-- right col -->
  </div>
```

**Model**

```
public function rangeDate($start_date,$end_date){

    $query = $this->db->select($this->tables['invent_inv'].'.id,'
    .$this->tables['invent_inv'].'.inv_type,'.$this->tables['invent_inv'].'.inv_cno,'
    .$this->tables['invent_cust'].'.id as custid,'.$this->tables['invent_cust'].'.cust_name,'
    .$this->tables['invent_inv'].'.inv_price, '.$this->tables['invent_inv'].'.inv_tax,'
    .$this->tables['invent_inv'].'.pay_due, SUM('.$this->tables['invent_sales'].'.paid_amnt) as payment,'
    .$this->tables['invent_inv'].'.timestamp')
        ->join($this->tables['invent_cust'], $this->tables['invent_inv'].'.cust_id='
    .$this->tables['invent_cust'].'.id','LEFT')
        ->join($this->tables['invent_sales'], $this->tables['invent_inv'].'.inv_cno='
    .$this->tables['invent_sales'].'.inv_cno','LEFT')
        ->where($this->tables['invent_inv'].'.status !=', 1)
        ->where($this->tables['invent_inv'].'.status !=', 0)
        ->where($this->tables['invent_inv'].'.timestamp >=',$start_date)
        ->where($this->tables['invent_inv'].'.timestamp <=',$end_date)
        ->group_by($this->tables['invent_sales'].".inv_cno")
        ->group_by($this->tables['invent_inv'].".inv_cno")
        ->group_by($this->tables['invent_inv'].".timestamp")
        ->get($this->tables['invent_inv']);

    return $query;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#start_date').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  autoclose: true
})

$('#end_date').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  autoclose: true
})

$('#table-sales').DataTable();
```

[image]

Now my problem is that I don't know what to put on the controller and I don't know how to show it on my `table-sales` . I don't know if the code I am putting is correct or if I am on the right path . I'm using codeigniter3x . Could someone help me please.

Thank you in advance for someone who will help me .

Comment: Could you please display you code where you are showing data in datatales. Please explain in detail (Post all code)

Comment: @ambapatel edited my question and posted the code to show datatable

Answer (score 0):

1. You can call ajax when click on `Search` button and pass start and end date as parameters in ajax request and filter data.
2. After get ajax response  from controller you can update `tbody` of `table-sales` table using jquery with updated data.
   Example 
   Assume you get array of updated data
   var tab_body = '';

   ```
       $.each(sub_subject, function (key, value)
       {
           tab_body = tab_body + '<tr><td>' + value.sub_subject_name + '</td>' +
                   '<td>' + value.sub_subject_code + '</td>' +
                   '<td><div class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-primary open_edit_sub_subject_model"  sub_subject_id="' + value.sub_subject_id + '"  type="button" title="Edit" request_type="open_edit" subject_name="' + d.subject_name + '"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>\n\
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary subject-data-delete" title="Remove" delete_type="sub_subject" subject_group_id="' + d.subject_group_id + '" subject_id="' + d.subject_id + '" sub_subject_id="' + value.sub_subject_id + '"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>\n\
                    </div></td>' +
                   '</tr>';
       });
       // example is just for reference
       put above data in table using
       $("#table-sales tbody").html(tab_body);
   ```

   Hopfully it will help.

Comment: I don't quite understand this sir. Could you explain a bit more. If you don't mind

Comment: Are you familiar with ajax call ?